# Angular2 - Changing property onClick doesn't trigger view update

Tags: angular

i'm trying to re-create the [TodoMvc app in Angular2](http://todomvc.com/).

I'm struggling with filtering the list based off a click event.
[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-driscoll-x685g?file=/src/app/todo-list/todo-list.component.ts)

[image]

The flow is as follows:

1. App renders with `this.todoItemFilter = TodoItemFilter.All` and `*ngFor="let item of todoItems | filter: filterTodoItems"`
2. Clicking `All/Active/Completed` results in a function call `setSelectedFilter(todoItemFilterEnum.All)` which updates the filter property `this.todoItemFilter = filter;` **but view is not re-rendered.**

I'm pretty sure there are multiple ways to solve this problem i'm actually interesting in as many as possible thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a new reference to todoItems:

```
  setSelectedFilter(filter: TodoItemFilter) {
      this.todoItemFilter = filter;
      this.todoItems = [...this.todoItems];
  }
```

This will cause the change detection to detect a 'new' value.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the items from original list?

Comment: After this: all items from this.todoItems are in the 'new' this.todoItems. this.todoItems will get a new reference. The reference of each todo will be the same.

Comment: I see so we're triggering the re'render by changing the reference. Clever, any other ideas maybe binding it differently?

Comment: You can inject the cdr in the component constructor:  constructor(private readonly cdr: ChangeDetectorRef  )  and in setSelectedFilter:   this.cdr.detectChanges();

Comment: this.cdr.detectChanges() makes sense if your component is set to  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)